# Casas decimais no template do Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-2.0

Bom dia pessoal,

Estou com um problema básico mas, aparentemente, chatinho para resolver:

```
{% load l10n %}
{% localize off %}
    var dados_grafico = [
        [
            'Entradas',
            {{relatorio.grafico.entradas|floatformat:2}},
            {{relatorio.grafico.saidas|floatformat:2}},
        ]
    ]
{% endlocalize %}
```

Pela documentação do Django, supondo que eu tenho 10 para entradas e 7 para saídas, isso deveria retornar 10.00 e 7.00 respectivamente, **com pontos separando as casas decimais**, que é o que desejo.

O problema é que está retornando 10,00 e 7,00 (**com vírgulas separando as casas decimais**).

Reparei também que, ao retirar o *floatformat:2* dos valores, o Django retorna, por exemplo, 10.000 e 7.000 (funciona mas não limita o número de casas decimais).

**Pergunta:** Alguém já passou por isso e pode me dar uma luz?

Answer (score 2):

Voce pode mudar isso no seu arquivo `settings.py`, mas veja que para o nosso sistema o "correto", é separar casas decimais com vírgulas e não com ponto, o tópico [Format localization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/formatting/) na documentação diz que a formatação é desabilitada por default, então provavelmente vc deve ter o seguinte comando em seu `settings.py`:

```
USE_L10N = True
```

Embora a formatação local é desabilitada por default, quando voce cria um projeto com `django-admin startproject`, por conveniencia, `USE_L10N = True` é incluido em seu `settings`. Tente retirar essa linha ou mudar para:

```
USE_L10N = False
```

Note que isso afetará outros detalhes da formatação local (Brasil).

**intcoma (django.contrib.humanize):**

Uma opção é utilizar o `[django.contrib.humanize][2]` "Um conjunto de filtros de template que adiciona um 'toque humano' aos dados"

intcomma convert um `int` ou `float` (ou uma representação em string) para uma string contendo vírgulas a cada 3 digitos:

Exemplos:

```
4500 se torna 4,500
4500.2 se torna 4,500.2
```

Não sei se essa opcao atenderia especificamente o seu caso, para utiliza-la, adicione em `INSTALLED_APPS` e na template que for usar `{% load humanize %}`

Comment: Então... Só que nesse caso eu teria que tratar todos os outros números do meu projeto para que apareçam com a vírgula como caractere separador das casas decimais. Meu intuito era fazer apenas esse conjunto de dados ter essa configuração, entende?

Comment: @illozzaM Não entendi. Se vc alterar o seu settings, todo o seu projeto vai funcionar da acordo com a nova configuração, de qq forma, adicionei uma opção na resposta, por outro lada, se é que é para um caso específico, não seria mais facil converter para string no formato que vc quer, no back-end e enviar ja formatado para a template?

Comment: Exato, Sidon! Eu fiz algo parecido convertendo via Javascript no meu template. Obrigado! :)

Answer (score 0):

O óbvio, muitas vezes, é a última coisa que nos ocorre:

```
    var dados_grafico = [
        [
            'Entradas',
            parseFloat('{{relatorio.grafico.entradas|floatformat:2}}'.replace(',', '.')),
            parseFloat('{{relatorio.grafico.saidas|floatformat:2}}'.replace(',', '.')),
        ]
    ]
```

Dessa forma, o Django retornará o valor com a vírgula mas ela é modificada via Javascript pelo ponto. :-)

Comment: Eu não entendi, a sua primeira versão da pergunta ja estava assim (por isso investi meu tempo, achando q daquele jeito n servia p vc), vc editou, e colocou a primeira versão como resposta, da para explicar?

Comment: Não estava exatamente assim. Na primeira versão, eu estava utilizando os dados 'entradas' e 'saidas' sem as aspas, incluindo um '.toString()' para que o js convertesse o valor para string antes de fazer o replace. Isso não dava certo porque o django mostrava o valor com a tal vírgula no lugar do ponto desejado. Então, adicionar as aspas e retirar o '.toString()' possibilita ao js executar o '.replace()'. As outras modificações foram para tornar a resposta mais útil a outras pessoas que tiverem um problema parecido. Eu te agradeço muito pela ajuda pois você me ajudou a encontrar uma solução!

Comment: Sim, depois que vc editou a resposta tb, ficou, digamos,,,, um pouco mais diferente, mas eu não tenho duvidas que a resposta é a propria pergunta. :-)